# PHP variable variable names with concatenated string

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have a mysql query:

```
$qry = "SELECT name,date,id,size from table";
$stmt = $db->query($qry);
while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
      foreach ($r as $k => $v){
          $$k = $v;
      }
}
```

This makes sense and works fine.  It gives me variables such as:

```
    $name = 'someVal';
    $date = 'someOtherVal';
```

Let's say now I want to do another query that may have fields that overlap.  I want to prepend a "t_" to the variable name given the same format.

```
$qry = "SELECT name,occupation,date from otherTable";
$stmt = $db->query($qry);
while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
      foreach ($r as $k => $v){
          $$k = $v;
      }
}
```

How can i have it so this query's results give me varaible names with an prepended "t_";

```
 $t_name = 'someVal';
 $t_occupation = 'someOtherVal';
```

Comment: $kk in your first example must be $$k, same in third code block

Comment: edited.  thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: again in third block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $qry = "SELECT name,occupation,date from otherTable";
 $stmt = $db->query($qry);
 while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
    foreach ($r as $k => $v){
        $varname = "t_".$k;
        $$varname = $v;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
$$k = $v;
```

for

```
$$("t_".$k) = $v;
```

It will work.